# Python breadth first search type error

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

In my Python Script for Breadth first search i get the following error:

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Here is the Code:

```
initialState = sys.argv[2]
initialState = [i for i in initialState.split(',')]
goalTest = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8']

def bfs(initialState, goalTest):
    q = deque([])
    for item in initialState:
        q.appendleft(item)
        print q

    frontier = q
    explored = set()

    while not frontier <= len(frontier):
        state = frontier.pop()
        print state
        explored.add(state)

        if goalTest(state):
            return state

        for neighbor in state.neighbors():
            if neighbor not in frontier or explored:
                frontier.append(neighbor)

    return "FAILURE"
```

So the line `if goalTest(state)` throws the `TypeError`, why?

Comment: The error is self explanatory, `goalTest` is a list and you're trying to pass an argument to it like a function; and fix your indentation

Comment: ok i am a web frontend developer and a newbee in python. I just startet a AI Course and this is just a unit for the programming lecture. so i run into problems every time an d didn't understand really whats going on. I hope for help. Maybe when i got an runable sccipt i can better understand it. And the frontier is because 'while not frontier:' didn't work. And i try to understand the neighbor think also.

Comment: You should add how exactly your input looks, and what are the "beighbors" of a given state, then we might be able to help.

Comment: it is a 8puzzel solution unit. so i start the script with `python driver.py bfs 1,2,3,4,5,8,7,0,6` about th neighbors i don not know it comes from the pseudocode in the presentation.

Comment: line `while not frontier <= len(frontier):` makes no sense - rather `while len(frontier) > 0:` or   `while len(frontier):` or even `for state in frontier:` instead of `while`.

Comment: BTW: you can do `initialState = initialState.split(',')` or even `initialState = sys.argv[2].split(',')`

Comment: ok, thx and how can i make a neighbors method?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few problems with your code:

- if you want to add the states to a `set` of visited states, they have to be `tuple`, as `list` is not hashable
- don't add the individual items from the state to the `deque`, just the state as a whole
- if this is supposed to be a BFS, you have to use `deque.popleft` so it behaves like a FIFO queue; using `pop` you have a LIFO queue, or stack, i.e. a DFS (depth first search)
- `while not frontier <= len(frontier)` does not make sense; you probably want `while len(frontier) > 0` or just `while frontier`
- `goalTest` is just a reference state, so you should just compare: `if state == goalTest`
- `neighbors` is not a method of `state` (which is just a list or tuple) but should be a function, thus call it like `neighbors(state)` instead of `state.neighbors()`
- `neighbor not in frontier or explored` does not check whether `neighbor` is in neither of those lists, but `(neighbor not in frontier) or explored`; also, no need to check whether it is in `frontier` if you add it to `explored` right away
- instead of `return "FAILURE"`, you should just `return False` or `return None`

Here's a fixed (but not thoroughly tested) version:

```
initialState = tuple(initialState.split(','))
goalTest = ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8')

def bfs(initialState, goalTest):
    frontier = collections.deque([initialState])
    explored = set()

    while frontier:
        state = frontier.popleft()
        print(repr(state), len(frontier), len(explored))

        if state == goalTest:
            return state

        for neighbor in neighbors(state):
            if neighbor not in explored:
                frontier.append(neighbor)
                explored.add(neighbor)
    return False

def neighbors(state):
    ...
```

Implementing `neighbors` is left as an exercise to the reader. If this is, [as you say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41890829/python-breadth-first-search-type-error/41894292#comment70965004_41890829), an [8-puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle), then `0` is supposed to be the "blank" space in the puzzle. Just check which of the other pieces are adjacent to it (hint: division and modulo are your friends) and swap those pieces, then return a list of those swapped states.

Also, note that BFS might not be the best algorithm for this problem, since there are *a lot* of states, and uninformed search, such as BFS, can take very, very long. Better use informed search, such as [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), using e.g. the number of misplaced tiles as a heuristic.